# Multiline lambda comparator

Tags: java, lambda, javafx

I am starting with the lambda expressions in Java and there is something that I consider bizarre and I am sure that I am doing something wrong or it has a workaround.

To define a comparator, I can do:

```
 col.setComparator((CustomCell o1, CustomCell o2) ->
            ((Comparable) o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue())
        );
```

Which is great, however, if I just add two "{". I get a compilation error:

```
 col.setComparator((CustomCell o1, CustomCell o2) -> {
            ((Comparable) o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        });
```

The error is not related to the "{", but to `setComparator`:

```
The method setComparator(Comparator<CustomCell>) in the type 
TableColumnBase<CustomParentCell,CustomCell> is not applicable for the arguments 
((CustomCell o1, CustomCell o2) -> {})
```

I have tried using the multiline statements before for actionevents and it does work:

```
 setOnAction(event -> {
        // do something
 });
```

Is it because it only has one argument?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The method you are implementing with `setOnAction` is

```
public void handleEvent(ActionEvent event) ;
```

It has a return type of `void`: i.e. it doesn't return anything:

The method you are implementing with `setComparator` is

```
public int compare(CustomCell cell1, CustomCell cell2) ;
```

which returns a value. To use the longer form, you must have an explicit return statement for methods that return a value:

```
col.setComparator((CustomCell o1, CustomCell o2) -> {
        return ((Comparable) o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is the reason. The error I was getting was not very helpful.