# Multiline lambda

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I have this code, which works:

```
  new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(c, true))
        .query("select id, name from PLAYERS", (rs, rowNum) ->
            new Player(rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("name")) // oneline
        );
```

However I now need to add multiple statements in the new Player() part. I tried enclosing them in brackets, but it doesn't seem to work. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Post the code you tried and didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline lambda comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150608/multiline-lambda-comparator)

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming the method of the functional interface implemented by this lambda expression has a return value, so when using brackets, it should include a return statement, just like any method with non-void return type.

```
new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(c, true))
    .query("select id, name from PLAYERS", (rs, rowNum) ->
        {
            return new Player(rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("name");
        }) 
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

**Don't do that.** Having multiple statements in a `lambda` in most cases is a **code smell**. Rather create a method with two parameters:

```
private Player toPlayer(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
    // multiple setters here
    return player;
}
```

And then pass the `method reference` (which in fact will behave like a `BiFunction`) instead of `lambda`:

```
new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(c, true))
    .query("select id, name from PLAYERS", this::toPlayer);
```

---

One may want to create a static utility method instead of a dynamic one. The logic is the same as above:

```
public class MappingUtil {
    // ...
    public static Player toPlayer(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
        // multiple setters here
        return player;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(c, true))
    .query("select id, name from PLAYERS", MappingUtil::toPlayer);
```

Comment: My best guess is that some people judged that your answer was too opinionated; it would be better to explain why you think multi-line lambdas are bad style or otherwise problematic, to support it rather than asserting your opinion. That said, I think your answer is useful, so I upvoted.

Comment: Just for background reading, [Why the perfect lambda expression is just one line](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/articles/j-java8idioms6/) explains nicely why you could consider multiple statements in a lambda a code smell.